# Why can't I get the value of my Radiobutton?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I want to get the value of my Radiobutton but it doesn't work. It might be because of I'm trying to get a dictionary. This is my code:

```
vars = []
playersg={"Bob":"1", "Jeff":"2", "John":"3", "Adam":"4"}


def NextRound():
    j = 0
    playersg2 = []
    while j < len(vars):
        playersg2 += vars[j].get()
        print(j)
        print(vars[j].get())
        j += 1
    print(playersg2)

def match():
    matchw = Tk()
    matchw.withdraw()

    draw = 0

    vieww.withdraw()
    matchw.deiconify()
    matchw.title('Tournament Software')
    matchw.geometry("300x999900")
    matchw.configure(background="#1aff29")

    numPlayers = len(playersg)
    numDraws = numPlayers/2
    matches=Label(matchw, text="Matches", font="none 50 bold", bg="#1aff29", fg="black").pack()

    while draw < numDraws:
        frame = Frame(matchw, bg="#1aff29")
        frame.pack()

        var = StringVar()
        R1=Radiobutton(frame, text=playersg[draw], bg="#00e60f" , font="none 10 bold", fg="black",
                       command=NextRound, indicatoron = 0,
                       value = playersg[draw], variable=var)
        R1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)
        Label(frame, text = "vs", font = "none 10 bold", bg="#1aff29", fg="black").pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)
        R2=Radiobutton(frame, text=playersg[numPlayers-draw-1] , bg="#00e60f", font="none 10 bold", fg="black",
                       command=NextRound, indicatoron = 0,
                       value = playersg[numPlayers-draw-1], variable=var)
        R2.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)

        draw += 1
        print(var.get())
        vars.append(var)
```

There is no error but when I `print(var[j].get())`, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you explain it further what you want to get from the radiobutton, and also the code you provided is not complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value from radiobox in Tkinter - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547355/getting-value-from-radiobox-in-tkinter-python)

Comment: What do you think `vars[j].get()` and/or `var[j].get()` should return?

Comment: What is `vieww`? Is it another instance of `Tk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you need to put the window as an argument for `StringVar()`. If you do not put the window you want, it will use the main window by default. For my case, it should be like this

```
var = StringVar(matchw)
```

Comment: The only way this can possibly be the answer is if you're creating two instances of `Tk`, which you should never do. You didn't mention that in your question. Is your code creating more than one instance of `Tk`? I'm betting it does.

Answer (score 0):

`playersg[draw]` tries to access value with key of `draw`, which is a number, while there are no number keys in `playersg`.

Replace:

```
playersg={"Bob":"1", "Jeff":"2", "John":"3", "Adam":"4"}
```

with:

```
playersg = ["Bob", "Jeff", "John", "Adam"]
```

Which makes `playersg` a list instead of a dictionary.